# CypressError: Timed out retrying after 5000ms: `cy.wait()` timed out waiting `5000ms`

Tags: next.js, cypress

I have a Next.js project that has a login page. Now I want to write a test for it with Cypress. My test method is as follows:

```
describe('Test login by username', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {

        cy.intercept('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/api/login').as('myPost')
        cy.visit("/");

    });
    it('login', () => {


        cy.get('[data-tid="username"]')
            .type("admin")

        cy.get('[data-tid="password"]')
            .type("123")


        cy.get('[data-tid="user_email_login_btn"]')
            .click()

        cy.wait('@myPost')
            .then((interception) => {
                // read the response
                cy.task('log','--> status code is: ' + interception?.response?.statusCode)
                expect(interception?.response?.statusCode).to.eq(200)
            })
    })
})
```

cypress.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        log(message) {
          console.log(message)
          return null
        },
      })
    },
  },
})
```

Next and cypress version is:

```
"cypress": "^13.6.0"
"next": "14.0.3"
```

Now when i run test method by `cypress run --config http://localhost:3000` i get error as below:

`` CypressError: Timed out retrying after 5000ms: `cy.wait()` timed out waiting `5000ms` for the 1st request to the route: `myPost`. No request ever occurred. ``

I don't know what is problem . please help me

**EDIT**

My server code is a simple express post api that return 'hello world' text

```
app.get('/api/login' , (req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
    res.send('Hello World')
})
```

loginButton handler:

```
    const loginHandler = async () => {
        try {
            setLoginLoading(true)
            const result = await signIn("credentials", {
                username: username,
                password: password,
                redirect: false,
            }).then(({ok}) => {
                if (ok) {
                    showNotif(null);
                    setIsSuccessLogin(true);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        push("/panel");
                    }, 3000)

                } else {
                    showNotif({message: t("login_by_username_error_message"), notifType: 'error'});
                }
                setLoginLoading(false)
            })
        } catch (error) {
            setLoginLoading(false);
            showNotif({message: t("login_by_username_error_message"), notifType: 'error'});
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the complete URL that the request goes to? Your intercept has the localhost port as 5000, but your baseUrl in the config file has port 3000.

Comment: `cypress run --config http://localhost:3000` is missing the key part of the config - should be `cypress run --config baseUrl=http://localhost:3000`. But you already have same value in `cypress.config.ts` - what is the aim of putting a value in the command line?

Comment: Aside from that, can you please add the code for the login form (specifically for click handler of `user_email_login_btn`)

Comment: @Gino.Diamantopoulos
That's right , i remove it from cammand line . but the problem still exists.

I update post and add code of login form

Comment: You should check the Network tab of the browser Developer Tools console to see what URL is sent on the POST. Compare it to the `cy.intercept()` URL used. From the code you gave for the server, the simplest pattern would probably be `cy.intercept('POST', '**/api/login/*').as('myPost')`.

Comment: I assume you already know that ***`cy.wait()` timed out waiting `5000ms` for the 1st request*** error means that `http://localhost:5000/api/login` does not match the actual request.

Comment: Could it be due to cors error? Because frontend and backend is running on different address